# How can I remove excess padding in my contact form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I'm not really well-versed with HTML/Bootstrap and I need some help when it comes to my Contact Form.

I can't remove the excess padding in my form plus I wanted to make the submit button red and full-width. I'm also wondering, even if I decreased the width of the input, the "email" and "considering" can still be found below the name and phone.

[Here is a fiddle that I did.](https://jsfiddle.net/trishabiz/h4nowu5s/4/)

I'd appreciate the help.

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="form_lastname">Your Phone *</label>
      <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
      <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fairly confused by what you wanted but I did what I understood from the question in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h2yjfund/

Your input fields were stacked because you started a new row div. I put them all in the same row. I also edited the submit button like you asked and changed the header to center purely to make it all matched.

I'm not really sure what you meant by padding but if you mean the extra space between boxes, then you just need to adjust your margins for the element using margin:0px; or however many pixels you want.

```
style="margin:5px;"
```

I added all the styling as inline styling since you didn't provide a style sheet. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have a question.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to note:

- Rows in bootstrap have 12 columns, so if you want elements in your row to occupy the full width, their sizes should add up to 12. Your inputs were `col-md-3`, I made them `col-md-6`.
- You can make your button full width by giving it the `btn-block` class. Because of what I mentioned before, giving it the `col-md-20` class makes no sense, I made it `col-md-12`.
- Buttons can be red by giving them the `btn-danger` class.
- Containers in bootstrap will usually be as wide as possible by default. I gave your container the following property: `max-width: 600px`. Maybe a tidier approach would be to use media queries to give it different widths depending on the screen size, but that depends on what you're trying to do.

Here's the solution with these changes applied:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="border-radius:5px;background-color:#f56b00;max-width: 600px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 py-5">
        <h1>
          <font color="#ffffff">Schedule a Call With Us Today</font>
        </h1>

        <p class="lead"></p>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
          <div class="messages"></div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_name">Your Name *</label>
                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_lastname">Your Phone *</label>
                  <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                  <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_need">Considering *</label>
                  <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                    <option value="Request quotation">Buying</option>
                    <option value="Request order status">Selling</option>
                    <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Other</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send btn-danger btn-block" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-dHf/YjH1A4tewEsKUSmNnV05DDbfGN3g7NMq86xgGh8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="contact.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I think you should read the following:

- [Bootstrap buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/).
- [Bootrsrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

If you want all fields in a row:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="border-radius:5px;background-color:#f56b00;max-width: 600px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 py-5">
        <h1>
          <font color="#ffffff">Schedule a Call With Us Today</font>
        </h1>

        <p class="lead"></p>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
          <div class="messages"></div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_name">Your Name *</label>
                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_lastname">Your Phone *</label>
                  <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                  <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_need">Considering *</label>
                  <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                    <option value="Request quotation">Buying</option>
                    <option value="Request order status">Selling</option>
                    <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Other</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send btn-danger btn-block" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-dHf/YjH1A4tewEsKUSmNnV05DDbfGN3g7NMq86xgGh8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="contact.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It makes sense now. I'd like to ask what can I do in order to make the field one-liner in a one row?

I tried this code as a sample but it didn't work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```

Comment: I added a new snippet to my answer where all the fields are in one row. Since you have four fields and rows have 12 columns, each field must be `col-sm-3`. Note that if your viewport isn't wide enough they will stack. If you want them all in one line no matter the viewport size, you can use `col-3` instead, but that will look weird in small containers. 

Again, you should spend some time reading about the [bootrstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).